# Populating image on collectionview smoothly after fetching url from url in swift

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, alamofireimage

I have a url

```
 https://fotorusapi20161004041801.azurewebsites.net/api/fotorus/1
```

When I hit this url I get array of dictionaries as response.

```
[{
    "Height" : 700,
    "PreviewPath" : "http:\/\/mobisoftframe.azureedge.net\/previewframe\/pre_pip132.jpg",
    "CategoryName" : [
      "PIP"
    ],
    "Width" : 450,
    "FramePath" : "http:\/\/mobisoftframe.azureedge.net\/frames\/pip132.png",
    "LayoutID" : 132,
    "Frames" : [
      {
        "X" : 99,
        "Y" : 307,
        "isBlur" : false,
        "Height" : 245,
        "MaskImagePath" : null,
        "Width" : 238
      }
    ],
    "FrameCount" : 1
  },
  {
    "Height" : 700,
    "PreviewPath" : "http:\/\/mobisoftframe.azureedge.net\/previewframe\/pre_pip133.jpg",
    "CategoryName" : [
      "PIP"
    ],
    "Width" : 450,
    "FramePath" : "http:\/\/mobisoftframe.azureedge.net\/frames\/pip133.png",
    "LayoutID" : 133,
    "Frames" : [
      {
        "X" : 26,
        "Y" : 272,
        "isBlur" : false,
        "Height" : 182,
        "MaskImagePath" : null,
        "Width" : 190
      }
    ],
    "FrameCount" : 1
  }
]
```

I get more than 100 dictionaries like this  in response.

Code for fetching response is as follows:-

```
//MARK: Api Calling



     func callApi(category:String,completion:@escaping (Bool)-> Void) {
        NetworkClass().callApiService(categoryCount:category) { (result,error)  in
          guard let response = result else {
            hideProgressHud(view:self.view)
            self.showalert(message:(error?.localizedDescription)!, title:"")
            completion(false)
            return
          }

          let parsedPIPResponse = populatePIPResponse(jsonData: response)
          selectedCategoryPreviewPath.removeAll()
          for objects in parsedPIPResponse{
            selectedCategoryPreviewPath.append(objects.PreviewPath!)
          }
          completion(true)
        }
      }

//Now I am populating the collectionview as follows:-

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
      let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:"categoryHolderCVCell", for:indexPath)  as! CategoryHolderCVCell

      collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top:50, left: 0, bottom: 50, right: 0)
      let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:"frameCVCell", for:indexPath)  as! FrameCVCell
      let url = URL.init(string: selectedCategoryPreviewPath[indexPath.row])
      cell.frameCategoryImageView.af_setImage(
        withURL: url!,
        placeholderImage: nil,
        filter: nil,
        imageTransition:.noTransition,
        completion: { response in
      }
      )
      return cell

  }
```

On Selection of rows ,I am managing Data as follows:-

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      showProgressHud(view:self.view)

      callApi(category:String(indexPath.row+1)) { (success) in
        if(success){
          self.sliderHorizontalConstraint.constant = self.sliderView.frame.size.width*CGFloat(indexPath.item)
          UIView.animate(withDuration:0.75, delay:0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
          }, completion:nil)

          let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CategoryCVCell
          cell.tintColor = UIColor.blue

          self.selectedIndexPathRow = indexPath.row
          self.categoryCollectionView.reloadData()

          self.categoryHolderCollectionView.reloadData()
          hideProgressHud(view:self.view)
        }
      }

  }
```

This whole task is taking a lot time.I need help to reduce time and improve smoothness when I call api fetch imageurl and make user wait until it fetches all the image url ,so that i can use those urls to get thumbnail image.

I am implementing this first time.Kindly help or guide to improve the performance of task.

Any help or guidance would be appreciable .Thanks in advance!

Comment: Fetch data for visible cells and do loading for that and get data on scroll on load. Am talking paging concept

Comment: Store response in array not call complete with url inside code for cell. Or use lazy loading but will be also bad.

Comment: Try implementing pagination in the Backend. This include both Backend and front end changes, from your app you should send the start index of the page like 0, 1, .. and get 10 data at a time so your Backend API should also modify to support this pagination logic.